# Installation of Microsoft OneDrive Fails With: Microsoft OneDrive has stopped working

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

Upon attempting to install Microsoft OneDrive, I had the following experience

- The installation proceeded fine
- The Setup screens appeared.
- I see the screens below and then a dialog appears saying, "Microsoft OneDrive has stopped working"
- I am forced to exit the setup
- No matter how many times I uninstall / reinstall / reboot, I get the same experience

**Screenshot 1: Welcome**

[image: Welcome screenshot]

**Screenshot 2: Location**

[image: Location screenshot]

**Screenshot 3: Select Files.  Crash occurs here**

[image: Select Files. Crash occurs here screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OneDrive installation produced the following folder:

```
\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SkyDrive\17.3.1229.0918
```

with the following file:

```
OneDriveSetup.exe
```

It turned out that when I ran that setup, the setup completed and OneDrive seems to work just fine.

**Bottom Line**:  If the downloaded OneDriveSetup.exe in your download folder crashes, try running the OneDriveSetup.exe from the AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\ folder.

Good Luck!